# VSTS: use WebTestRequest in custom app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webtest

I have some web calls that are being performed inside WebTestRequest's under VSTS Web Performance tests.

I am curious if I can use the WebTestRequest code in my own WPF application.  Ultimately, It would be much easier to copy/paste the code generated from these requests instead of rewriting and trying to preserve the complexities of hidden variables, form post data, and redirects. (aka the tests work fine as is, but I need a GUI for my team)

Is there a specific way to 'execute' these tests with code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you cannot use the request code in your own program but there may be some difficulties in doing so.

Web Performance Tests are part of Visual Studio Ultimate. There may be licencing issues if you take the code elsewhere or put it into other programs. I stress "may be" because I have not looked at that part of my licence and your licence may be different (for a different country) to mine.

Web Performance Tests can be converted in C# code, there is a command icon in the Web Test editor to invoke the conversion (see the note below.) Pieces of this code can easily be copied into your own program.

Web Performance Tests rely upon a number of DLLs to really run the test and collect data about how the test has run. The interfaces to these DLLs are not well documented, or at least I have not found much documentation. Tests can be run from the command line with ["mstest.exe" and other programs](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7561/how-to-choose-between-tcm-exe-mstest-exe-and-vstest-console-exe). There are several questions on Stackoverflow and elsewhere on the web about how to run Visual Studio tests from within your own program or where Visual Studio is not installed. Many of the answers to them include copying and linking to lots of DLLs. A variation on this is to install the Visual Studio Agent software, it seems to include all the DLLs needed to run a test.

---

**Note**: I believe that when you run a Web Test that that conversion to C# code is done and written to a temporary for executing the test. Sometimes when Web Test starts I have seen the bottom left of the Visual Studio window showing words lke "Building" and "Build successful".)